# Why am I receiving the following error message when running the ng serve command?

Tags: angular

I keep getting the following error message when running ng serve command.  How can I resolve this issue?

You seem to not be dependending on "@angular/core". This is an error.

Comment: recheck your package.json file. I recommend you downloading the latest quick seed from angular.io

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget running `npm install` after setting up. That should do it.

Comment: Indeed...that's a common mistake ..
running ng new <project)name>  will create a new template for sure... however the node_modules content is still empty at this stage... so executing
npm install BEFORE running ng serve is the right path. ;)

Answer (score 1):

happened to me. I wasn't running ng serve from the root folder

Answer (score 0):

You have deleted your config files (e.g. angular-cli.json, karma.config.js etc) and most likely node modules.

Just restore all your config files and required node_modules.

Comment: How do I do this?  Can you look at the below steps I took to install Angular 2?  1. npm install -g angular-cli 2.  ng new app  3. ng serve