# ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem when I try to run `ng serve` on a recently created Angular project.
The version I'm using is 9.1.4, this error does not occur on a project with an older Angular version.

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.4
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.4
@angular/cli                      9.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.4
@schematics/angular               9.1.4
@schematics/update                0.901.4
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

After executing `ng serve` or `ng build`:

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 2 kB [initial] [rendered]<br>
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 679 bytes [initial] [rendered]<br>
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]<br>
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 12.4 kB [initial] [rendered]<br>
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 339 kB [initial] [rendered]<br>
Date: 2020-05-08T02:06:46.145Z - Hash: 1a1b937f0ca2bb37634b - Time: 4087ms<br>

**ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined**
    at resolveAlias (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36513:37)
    at checkAliasSymbol (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64502:26)
    at checkImportBinding (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64534:13)
    at checkImportDeclaration (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64552:29)
    at checkSourceElementWorker (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64961:28)
    at checkSourceElement (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64800:17)
    at Object.forEach (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:317:30)
    at checkSourceFileWorker (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65123:20)
    at checkSourceFile (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65091:13)
    at getDiagnosticsWorker (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65179:17)
    at Object.getDiagnostics (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65165:24)
    at C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98703:85
    at runWithCancellationToken (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98665:24)
    at getBindAndCheckDiagnosticsForFileNoCache (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98691:20)
    at getAndCacheDiagnostics (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98956:26)
    at getBindAndCheckDiagnosticsForFile (C:\Cursos\Angular\ang-hello-world\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98688:20)

** **Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/** **
```

The result I get on my browser after running this project is:

```
Cannot GET /
```

Comment: Still getting this in Angular 11.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**edit**

If you use angular 9.1.6 it should be fine now

```
npm update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

**original post**

Something is broken in Angular 9.1.5 - if you run the following it should work:

```
npm install @angular/core@9.1.4 @angular/animations@9.1.4 @angular/common@9.1.4 @angular/forms@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser@9.1.4 @angular/router@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.4 @angular/compiler@9.1.4 @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.4 @angular/language-service@9.1.4

ng build
```

Just spent about 4-5 hours trying to fix it myself...

The issue seems to stem from using Angular CLI 9.1.4 with Angular 9.1.5 (most likely the compiler

You'll see the issue when you do

```
ng --version
```

if you get:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.4
Node: 12.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.5
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes
```

Then you will need to follow the npm installs i listed above

Comment: Thanks also worked. I can confirm, this problem appeared exactly when I upgraded from 9.1.4 to 9.1.5.

Comment: It worked for me too. Thanks. 9.1.5 @angular/cli is no longer available on npm.

Comment: @Matt Can you tell me which version of node you have used?

Comment: @KiranRacherla I'm using node v12.16.3'

Comment: In package.json file I've just removed '~' before all package with "~9.1.4".
and adjusted version for @angular/animations (previously with "~9.1.5") as follow : "@angular/animations": "9.1.4".

I'm working with last version of nodeJS (it's not the source of the problem) : 
$ nvm list
* 14.2.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)

Comment: I just did the next steps: npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.4, before i check the TypeScript Version, the version was 3.5.3, works well with angular 9.1.4, now i can run the **ng serve** command..., I think, the problem was I upgraded from 9.1.4 to 9.1.5...

Comment: Seeing this in angular 11.2.4 with webpack/yarn and typescript at 4.1.6 - its driving us crazy.

Answer (score 4):

9.1.6 just released, should fix that issue

Answer (score 4):

Got the same problem updating from 10.1.0 to 11.1.1.

Updating TypeScript to the latest Version from 4.0.2 to 4.1.3 solved the problem:

`npm i typescript@latest`

Comment: Thanks! Had the same issue and that solved it.

Answer (score 3):

@Matt's answer worked for me as well for **ng serve**, but needed additional steps.
First do these steps "Quoting the steps from his answer":

1. First check `ng --version`. Go to next step if you get:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.4
Node: 12.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.5
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes
```

2. Force reinstall the angular packages with 9.1.4 as the version using:

```
npm install @angular/core@9.1.4 @angular/animations@9.1.4 @angular/common@9.1.4 @angular/forms@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser@9.1.4 @angular/router@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.4 @angular/compiler@9.1.4 @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.4 @angular/language-service@9.1.4
```

Couple of more steps for more `ng serve` to finally work.

1. Next error I got was about tslib: `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'tslib'`
   For this I installed the tslib package manually using npm.
2. Next error I got was `You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core" and/or "rxjs". This is an error.`. For this I referred ["You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core"."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49537782/you-seem-to-not-be-depending-on-angular-core) and voila! ng serve worked!

Answer (score 2):

try this solution :

```
npm install @angular/core@9.1.4 @angular/animations@9.1.4 @angular/common@9.1.4 @angular/forms@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser@9.1.4 @angular/router@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.4 @angular/compiler@9.1.4 @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.4 @angular/language-service@9.1.4

npm install

ng serve
```