# Initializing angular project fails

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, compilation

I am trying to set up angular project from scratch.

Below are the steps followed

- Installed Node js
- Installed Angular CLI using npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

  Versions
  Angular CLI: 9.1.4
  Node: 12.16.3
  OS: win32 x64

  Angular:
  ...
  Ivy Workspace:

  ### Package                      Version

  @angular-devkit/architect    0.901.4
  @angular-devkit/core         9.1.4
  @angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.4
  @schematics/angular          9.1.4
  @schematics/update           0.901.4
  rxjs                         6.5.4

Created a new app using ng new app_name
 While trying to run the app through command ng serve I am getting a host of errors and app is not starting up

Have attached screen shot of the error[image]

Comment: Please check this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20794

Comment: I recreated your steps, and the problems is that you installing the latest version of angular. You should have used : npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: @EdwinSilva I had tried that and the CLI is version 9.1.4 but when you call "ng new <projectname>" it made projects with 9.1.5 by default. I had even done complete uninstalls of node/npm etc
The issue occurs even on completely fresh installs of nodeJS/npm/angular

Comment: You have to uninstall angular

Comment: @EdwinSilva It is because its a bug - its recommended to rollback as per my answer: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36993

Comment: @matt  So If I uninstall angular and node js then which version should i reinstall to make it work ?

Comment: @EdwinSilva Does using -g @angular/cli resolved the issue for you ?

Comment: You shouldnt need to uninstall just run: npm install @angular/core@9.1.4 @angular/animations@9.1.4 @angular/common@9.1.4 @angular/forms@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser@9.1.4 @angular/router@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.4 @angular/compiler@9.1.4 @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.4 @angular/language-service@9.1.4

your cli is fine but the Angular packages arent. that npm should resolve the issue above - I've amended my answer to try better explain. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**

If you use angular 9.1.6 it should be fine now

```
npm update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

**original post**

I had the same problem after making a fresh project using

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new <projectname>
```

I believe its a bug in 9.1.5 Angular when using the 9.1.4 cli

You'll see the issue when you do

```
ng --version
```

if you get:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.4
Node: 12.16.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.5
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes
```

To resolve you install 9.1.4 Angular instead by running after you've done your

```
ng new <projectname>
```

then run

```
npm install @angular/core@9.1.4 @angular/animations@9.1.4 @angular/common@9.1.4 @angular/forms@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser@9.1.4 @angular/router@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.4 @angular/compiler@9.1.4 @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.4 @angular/language-service@9.1.4

ng build
```

See my other answer for reference

[ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670882/error-in-typeerror-cannot-read-property-flags-of-undefined/61671596#61671596)

Comment: @Nupur no problem, could you mark it as the answer :)