# CMD and VS Code shows different versions of angular when checked simultaneously, is there something I may be missing during installation?

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio-code

I'm really new to angular and have no idea, but when I checked `ng --version` in `cmd` it showed Angular CLI 9.1.1 but when I checked in Visual Studio Code `ng --version`, it showed Angular CLI 9.1.4. 
Is there anything I'm missing out or does it work like this?

[image: CMD]

[image: VS Code]

Answer (score 0):

#### It's entirely possible that your local CLI version is different to your project CLI.

[image]

Angular allows you to have differing version of Angular CLI installed (i.e. your local instillation vs your `package.json` version). Obviously though, the project will rely on the `package.json` version

Comment: While learning I made few new angular projects using ng new ABC or CDE likewise, but now after creating 3-4 projects in the 5th project, it is showing some error as discussed in this thread  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670882/error-in-typeerror-cannot-read-property-flags-of-undefined . Just need to know if I am going in a right direction. Is it common to get such obstacles? Seeing my screenshots, everything looks fine ?

Answer (score 0):

You do need to upgrade the local Angular CLI version as well. To upgrade the local Angular CLI version in your Angular project, simply use the following command in the root directory.

Make sure to run the command below in the root of your Angular project to upgrade the local Angular CLI version:

npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest