# ERROR in Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm running into an issue when I run my Angular project where I get the following error:

> ERROR in Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

I read in some places that I need to be in version 9.1.4 or greater and I updated my project and still got the same issues. I have an other project running with my same package.json information listed below and it runs. The only difference is that the other project is not using *@angular-builders/custom-webpack*

```
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/animations": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "~9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "9.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.7",
```

Resources I used:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36992
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17665
- [ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61670882/error-in-typeerror-cannot-read-property-flags-of-undefined)